# Openshift 4 RBAC

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

What I have:

1. default install of Openshift 4.6
2. 3 master/worker nodes in the cluster
3. already configured OAuth
4. self-provisioner role from the system-auth group already been removed

Detail Question/Objective:
Assigning a self-provisioner role to a user allows the user to create a project and any resources inside the project, what I want to achieve is, a user who can create a project, but does not have any further rights/permission inside the project. Is this even possible?

Documentation of Openshift 4.6 tells, that any user creates a project, the user(requester) will become the admin of that project, this is because Openshift API will use a default template whenever it creates a project.

I'm confused about where do I do the changes to reflect my objective, is it the template or use any different RBAC role.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to customize the Project Template. Look here https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/applications/projects/configuring-project-creation.html#modifying-template-for-new-projects_configuring-project-creation

First you need to backup a project project-template from openshift-config, to be honest I don't know how to do it. If anyone find a way please drop the comment under the answer. - *Look at first answer bellow from @Stevencommy*

To create a new Project Template

```
oc adm create-bootstrap-project-template -o yaml > template.yaml
```

In `template.yml` configure

```
kind: Project
...
    name: ${PROJECT_NAME}
```

the default user for newly created project is configured in

```
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: <YOUR_USER_WITHOUT_RIGHTS_TO_CREATE_PROJECT>
```

Then create the template

```
oc create -f template.yaml -n openshift-config
```

Update

```
oc edit project.config.openshift.io/cluster
```

there

```
spec:
  projectRequestTemplate:
    name: <template_name>
```

`<template_name>` default is `project-request` you could also list with `oc get templates -n openshift-config | grep project-request`

If everything goes well you could test it with `oc new-project <your-project>`. The `user` for project should be `<YOUR_USER_WITHOUT_RIGHTS_TO_CREATE_PROJECT>`

Comment: Seems, according to the documentation, the default install does not have any template defined.  The API server creates a default template that creates a project with the requested name and assigns the requesting user to the admin role for that project.  So I guess there's nothing to backup. I tested, when you remove the template you create, it returns to the default install method. Thank You very much for your answer. Cheers

Comment: @Stevencommy Thank you for your answer. This is interesting fact.